# How to create an "encapsulated"/"existential" type within a JavaScript Flow Interface

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an interface with a type variable `cursor` that is only relevant to the methods within the interface:

```
interface OrderIndexI<cursor> {
  getCursor(): cursor;
  fromCursor(cursor): number;
}
```

When I implement this interface, the implementation class chooses what the `cursor` is supposed to be.

```
class OrderIndex1 implements OrderIndexI<Cursor1> { ... }
class OrderIndex2 implements OrderIndexI<Cursor2> { ... }
```

The user of this class will acquire the cursor types, but they can only use the interface methods on it, for intents and purposes, it is an opaque type.

However the above doesn't work when I want to use a generic function that works with any `OrderIndexI<*>` where the exact cursor type doesn't matter.

```
function genericWork (o: OrderIndexI<*>) { ... }
```

I have found that it only works doing this:

```
function genericWork (o: OrderIndexI<any>) { ... }
```

But I think it doesn't make sense to allow this to even be an option. The user should have some way of not explicitly saying that they can work with "any" `cursor`, since `cursor` was always only meant to be used by the interface methods. Is there a way to "hide" the `cursor` so it is not explicitly specified when users want to use `OrderIndexI`.

https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbQJIiwD2wB4EBXKAZwHsoA+ZAbwChlkBzCMAYXOqgAoAlAC5kZSjQDcLZDChUAtjwkDxfEchCkFAI2jSAvkyZgAngAcUyvsgC8jZHB0JRW3dGQHpCADZwKFGiYOHgQ+ACMyMAK5j4QChDggehYULgExNY09MysHNy8NMhCollQjDKsUJzkIA5OLsiRXjJGrHKKZcVqNKWFUBpueuW5rMjVYLVi-QB0DdKsRkYmFlb9AEx2DlgQrtrDnt5+AUGp6WGb0bHxiWDJwWmhhERl6zky+V0lyK8VY+M1KB1BjIHaiZoLTwyDpKfrdfp9FTrQb7DyjKqAuo9KAzHaQpbGGCkEAIMDAKh1MBwADWEAAKgALYCBfhUUQpEIZIgAKloKPcIxkcTAYi2VBmn36QkhEym4phZX4CEEhmMwuQVGAkXsIAgAHdTpywuFpUx1ZrNjr9YbHgR1qbjFTaYzmaytSqTDT6UyKG7kZIgA

In Haskell, this is solved with an existential type.

Answer (score 2):

Just define `genericWork` function as [generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-functions-with-generics):

```
function takeThis<T>(o: OrderIndexI<T>): number {
  let c = o.getCursor();
  return o.fromCursor(c);
}
```

Comment: I was more asking that `T` should be hidden competely. As in Haskell, the existential type is not known or even referred to at all.

Comment: Consumer not specifies type explicitly, it is inferred: `takeThis(oi1);`